# How to write and run unit test cases for angular 2 typescript without using any external framework?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, angular2-testing

I tried to write unit test cases with jasmine and karma for angular 2. But due to some issues I couldn't run using karma framework. Is it possible to write unit test cases for angular 2 application without using any external framework? Just simple unit test cases to test some functions or service calls? I have written unit test cases before using Nunit framework for C#. But I dont know how to write for angular 2 typescript without external frameworks and run the unit test cases. This latest guide of angular is using karma. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#testing-intro

Comment: Surely it's possible to do something like this but you're going to spend a lot of time re-inventing the wheel. You might be better off asking another question about the problems you had with getting Karma to work.

Comment: @SunilD.Okay Thank You. I will try to find solution using Karma